# JMeter set variable to random option

Tags: jmeter

I've been using JMeter and I'm aware of the `__Random` and `__RandomString` functions. I need to pick a random option and store it in a variable because it will be used as part of a parameter path for multiple calls. For example:

`http://www.example.com/pets/{random option such as: cat, dog, parakeet}/`

I've tried doing simple like this, where I set the variable `${query}` to `one`, `two`, or `three` using a random controller with userdefined variables as children. This seems like it *should* work, however I always get `${query}` set to `three`.

Any insight or ideas are will be well recieved. Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get random values from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694992/get-random-values-from-an-array)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) to generate random value

```
    String[] query = new String[]{"cat", "dog", "parakeet"};
    Random random = new Random();
    int i = random.nextInt(query.length);
    vars.put("randomOption",query[i]);
```

After that in your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

```
http://www.example.com/pets/${randomOption}
```

As an alternative to `String[] query = new String[]{"cat", "dog", "parakeet"};` you can use Beanshell pre-defined `Parameters` stanza.

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int i = random.nextInt(query.length);
    vars.put("randomOption",bsh.args[i]);
```

Comment: I like this, but how much of a performance hit would this add to the test? We're spawning 140 threads to test our pre-production server, which is why I opted out of using javascript.

Comment: After looking for about a month, this is the best answer that I can find. It works well, it looks like the calls that I utilize Beanshell PreProcessors seem to take slightly longer, but that's the price you pay.

Comment: Beanshell is the easiest way to get things done. If you need performance you may wish to consider JSR223 Sampler with Groovy language or even writing your own JavaRequest Sampler. See scripting extensions performance comparison assessment for details: http://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post and there is a new function available:

```
__RandomFromMultipleVars(animalCat|animalDog|animalParakeet, query)
```

somewhere you need to define the variables:

```
animalCat=cat
animalDog=dog
animalParakeet=parakeet
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is not a feature of Jmeter natively. I'm using a plugin that accomplishes this goal. http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/ implements a new function that lets you  choose a random string from a list of strings. From their website:

```
${__chooseRandom(red,green,blue,orange,violet,magenta,randomColor)}
```

Answer (score 0):

See also:

[Get random values from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694992/get-random-values-from-an-array)

This however requires writing some code in a PreProcessor.