# How can I access a record randomly in a list of 100 records through JMeter components and functions?

Tags: jmeter

Say, in a list view there are 100 records. I'm landing on the list view page of 100 records through HTTP request and want to access a record randomly from the list? Please help.

Example: 
- I'm using the Hubspot free CRM and I have created some contacts.
- The list view records appearance here. [ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rte5H.png)
- First I'm landing to the HubSpot contacts list view page and I would like to randomly open any one of the contact records from the list. [Open Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMXsh.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random selection from CSV file in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479960/random-selection-from-csv-file-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression extractor element with valid regular expression and '0' in Match No.